# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}$ as $h \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

In what follows $z,h \in \mathbb{C}$.

I do not see how $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}$ equals $e^0=1$, i.e. the derivative of the exponential function evaluated at zero. I am confused by the z variable in the expression. Can I get rid of it by defining a new variable $z':= 2zh$?

I am still confused:

If I set $z':= 2zh$, why $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}$ is equivalent to $\lim_{z'\to 0} \frac{e^{z'}-1}{z'}$, which then by definition is indeed $e^0$?

Comment: You definitely can.

Comment: "Can I get rid of it by defining $y=2zh$"

Yes, you can. Does that alleviate your confusion though, or is there still some remaining?

Comment: @MichaelHartley, I'm still confused - I edited the question.

Comment: Yes, since$$\lim_{z'\to0}\frac{e^{z'}-e^0}{z'}=\frac d{dz'}e^{z'}\bigg|_{z'=0}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Yes yes, I meant why are those two limits in my question equivalent. I know why the one on the RHS has value 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(w)=e^w$. It is known that $f'(0)=1$, which by the *definition of derivatives* means

> $$
> \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1\tag{1}
> $$

which by the *definition of limits* means

> for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta$, then
>   $$
> \left|\frac{e^h-1}{h}-1\right|<\epsilon\tag{2}
> $$

Now fix $z\neq 0$. Let's prove by **definition** that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}=1.
$$

Suppose $\epsilon>0$, you want to find $\delta'>0$ such that 
$$
\left|\frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}-1\right|<\epsilon\tag{3}
$$
whenever $0<|h|<\delta'$. But you just learned from (2) that there exits $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|2zh|<\delta$, which is equivalent to
$$
0<|h|<\frac{\delta}{2|z|},
$$
then (3) is true. Thus, you can take $\delta'=\frac{\delta}{2|z|}$.

Comment: This answer is the correct, fully technical answer. The hand-wavy, intuitive answer is "as h goes to zero, 2zh also goes to zero, so $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dots = \lim_{2zh\rightarrow 0}\dots$$

Comment: So, we have to prove $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}=1$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, right? But by seeing it as a constant in this proof, we do prove it for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, because the proof doesn't depend on what value $z$ takes (apart from $0$).

Comment: @MichaelHartley: of course I was using this "hand-wavy" way, but it didn't feel right.

Comment: @Kristina: the expression $\frac{e^{2zh}-1}{2zh}$ is not defined for $z=0$. The limit is only true for ${\bf C}\backslash\{0\}$. When one says "Now fix $z\neq 0$", it means for *arbitrary* nonzero $z$.

Comment: Yes and then in the proof we treat $z$ as a constant, rather than a variable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

**Possible Clarification**: (By Taylor) 
$$
e^{2zh} = 1 + 2zh + h^2\times(\text{Rem})
$$
where $\text{Rem}$ is some bounded remainder term. So, in the numerator, you have
$$
e^{2zh} - 1 = 2zh + h^2\times\text{Rem}
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{e^{2zh} - 1}{2zh} = \frac{2zh + h^2\times\text{Rem}}{2zh} = 1 + h\times\frac{\text{Rem}}{2z}
$$
Now, take $h \to 0$.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation, but I am looking for an answer "from first principles".